# NUnit/Selenium C# project - want to call all tests from default page

Tags: selenium, testing, nunit

I have just created a solution with 2 projects. 1 project has just a default web page and the other project has various classes with test cases in them.

What I would like to do (tried to google but no luck) is call all the classes/test cases from the default page. My default page inherits the page class.

I have a login public class that has 2 [Test] methods that verify a login page. One is called `public void VerifyLoginValid()`.

The namespace in the web project is `Selenium`

The namespace in the test project is `SeleniumTests`